# Multiple partitions of pendrive not visible in Windows

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive

I am using my friend's 8GB pendrive. It shows two partitions when connected to Ubuntu - 7.2GB and 200MB. However when connected to Windows it shows only 200MB.

How can I work around this problem or make it into a single partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its by design - windows officially only supports [one partition on removable media](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415), which is what thumbdrives are by default.

There are tools that flip the removable bit (I've not tried any, but lexar's bootit is the one i know of, but i can't find it) - which will allow partitioning, since the usb drive will be seen as a hard drive, which would probably be the easiest option.

You can probably combine the partitions (after copying out all the files) with gparted in linux, or any partition editor type programme in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of windows? It will also depend on what filesystem the 7.2GB is formatted with.

If you right click 'My Computer' and click on 'Manage', then goto 'Disk Management'.

Within here select the Removeable Disk in the top window which has the 200mb partition, it should tell you information regarding the other volume, such as the formatting used. If it is NTFS or FAT then right click on it and 'Choose/assign a drive letter'.

Comment: windows 7.. now on a linux machine.. will check in a windows machine and update..